# Can I use lipophilicity (partition coefficient) as a way to quantify solublity?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I am looking at investigating factors affecting the solubility of drugs using databases. So far, I am thinking of having my independent variables being the polar surface area, melting point, and size. My dependent variable would be lipophilicity. The reason why I am not directly measuring the solubility is that databases provide inconsistent solubility values.

Would quantifying solubility as lipophilicity be valid?

Comment: The same partition coefficient can be ratio of big numbers for one drug and small numbers for other drug.